# Add a class using jQuery after a delay

Tags: jquery, delay

When an element is clicked, I want to add a class to the body element, but with a slight delay.
So, element1 is clicked, then after .5 seconds, the body is a given a new class.

I was using this which works to an extent...

```
$('.element1').click(function() {
    $('body').delay(500).queue(function(){
        $(this).addClass('left-bg')
    });
});
```

However, I have another click event which removes this left-bg class from body.

```
$('.another-element').click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('left-bg');
});
```

But then the next time .element1 is clicked, it doesn't apply the left-bg class to the body at all.

Hope that makes sense. Can anybody help me with this or suggest another way of going about it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clear the queue:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uTShk/)

```
$('.element1').click(function() {
    $('body').delay(500).queue(function(){
        $(this).addClass('left-bg').clearQueue();
    });
});

$('.another-element').click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('left-bg');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to dequeue

```
$('.element1').click(function() {
    $('body').delay(500).queue(function(){
        $(this).addClass('left-bg');
        $(this).dequeue()
    });
});
```

as mentioned [here](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .stop()

```
$('.element1').click(function() {
    $('body').stop().delay(500).queue(function(){
        $(this).addClass('left-bg')
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9R2D/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

use this -

```
var bgch;
$('.element1').click(function() {
    bgch = setTimeout((function(){$('body').addClass('left-bg');}),500);
});
$('.another-element').click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('left-bg');
    clearTimeout(bgch);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind, that your delay can **cause a problem**:
 - pressing element1
 - pressing another-element
 - removing class
 - adding class after delay

To ensure all is working fine, you have to keep track of what is going on, as well as you **should check** if class is already on body-element, so the class is not applied twice:

```
var bodyClassTracker = 0;
var handledClass = 'left-bg';

$('.element1').click(function() {
    bodyClassTracker = 1;
    $('body').delay(500).queue(function(){
        var eleBody = $('body');
        if (!eleBody.hasClass(handledClass))
            eleBody.addClass(handledClass);
        bodyClassTracker = 0;
        eleBody.clearQueue();
    });
});

$('.another-element').click(function() {
    var removerFun = function(){
            var eleBody = $('body');
            if (eleBody.hasClass(handledClass))
                eleBody.removeClass(handledClass);
            eleBody.clearQueue();
        };
    if (bodyClassTracker == 1)
        $('body').delay(500).queue(removerFun);
    else
        removerFun();
});
```

Here you can test and demo the code.
http://jsfiddle.net/uTShk/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need to [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) the body after setting it.

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('body').delay(500).queue(function(){
        $(this).addClass('left-bg')
    }).stop();
});

$('#rem').click(function() {
    $('body').removeClass('left-bg');
});
```

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac4FV/1/)